# Image lazy loader for FTScroller (AngularJS)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

For my project I'm using ng-FTScroller (https://github.com/ftlabs/ftscroller) and I would also like to implement an image lazy loader module.
I've tried the few I've found, but they work with the body (or window) and I'm not able to use them with the FTScroller DIV (in my case it contains the ng-view).

Comment: Have you tried lazySizes: https://github.com/aFarkas/lazysizes/ ?

Comment: That's it!!! Thank you sooo much!!!

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use this library: https://github.com/GeneralElectric/winchjs

It listens on both scroll and animation events to recheck if a image is with in the view port (or close to) and trigger it to load.  You can also choose to trigger a manual recheck after a ngRouteChange event.